# Python Dice Roller - How can I total all dice?

Tags: python

I want to get the total amount of the dice results:

```
import random
min = 1
max = 6

numDices = 0
roll_again = "yes"
sum = 0

while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
    numDices = int(raw_input("how many dices "))
    for i in range(numDices):
        dicesArray = list(range(numDices))
        dicesArray[i] = random.randint(min, max)
        print(dicesArray[i])
        sum += dicesArray[i]
        print("sum ", sum)

    roll_again = raw_input("Roll the dices again? ")
```

but I get this when I run the code:

```
how many dices 3
4
('sum ', 4)
2
('sum ', 6)
6
('sum ', 12)
Roll the dices again?
```

Also, how can I limit the user to roll 1 to 5 dice max?

Thank you so much Python experts!

Answer (score 1):

You should change the indentation of the `print("sum")` statement so you only print the final sum. Also add a check for the dice number like below.

```
import random
min = 1
max = 6

numDices = 0
roll_again = "yes"

# Greeting here
print("Welcome to the dice rolling program!")
raw_input("Press any key to continue...")

while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
    sum = 0 # sum should be inside while loop
    numDices = int(raw_input("How many dice? "))
    if (numDices < 1 or numDices > 5):
        print("Allowed number of dice is 1 - 5. Please choose again.")
        continue
    for i in range(numDices):
        dicesArray = list(range(numDices))
        dicesArray[i] = random.randint(min, max)
        print(dicesArray[i])
        sum += dicesArray[i]
    print("sum: " + str(sum))

    roll_again = raw_input("Roll the dice again? ")
```

Comment: Thank you @Swazy, it works!, do you know how can I start the program with a greeting and the run the program as normal?, I also try to write the questions in Swedish but get encoding error when I use: å, ä and ö characters, it says: 

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file dice_roller_preject.py on line 19, but no encoding declared

Comment: @RicardoLinares - I've made a couple edits to my answer. The greeting could be done like I've shown with `print` and `raw_input` statements. I've also realised that the `sum` variable should probably be in the while loop (as shown) or it will keep on accumulating if the user rolls again and again!

Comment: If you would like to print characters like å and ä etc it would probably be best to start using Python 3 rather than Python 2 (which is what you're using at the moment). Python 3 stores strings as Unicode which can handle characters like that. NB: If you do start using Python 3 instead you'll need to replace all the `raw_input`s in your code with `input`s (the function got re-named). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check and make sure that `numDices` stays between 1 and 6. You can do that by adding an `if` condition before entering the `for` loop.

```
import random
min = 1
max = 6

numDices = 0
roll_again = "yes"
sum = 0

while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
    numDices = int(raw_input("how many dices "))
    if numDices < 1 or numDices > 6:
        print ("Invalid range. You can roll only between 1 and 5 times.")
        continue
    for i in range(numDices):
        dicesArray = list(range(numDices))
        dicesArray[i] = random.randint(min, max)
        print(dicesArray[i])
        sum += dicesArray[i]
        print("sum ", sum)

    roll_again = raw_input("Roll the dices again? ")
```